# Throw exception when file not found, in mathematica

Tags: exception, wolfram-mathematica, filenotfoundexception, throw

I have a function that processes an image whose path is given by the user. I'm a bit new to Mathematica, and I can't find much on its large documentation.  How can I throw an exception when Import[myFile] fails?  Can I even do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest do not forget to check if the file exists by `FileExistsQ` before `Import`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Throw[anyExpression]` or `Throw[anyExpression, exceptionTag]` to throw an exception, with any expression. You can then use `Catch[your code]` or `Catch[yourCode,exceptionPattern]`. Exceptions in Mathematica are not objects like in e.g. Java, so you can not directly use the technique of building exception inheritance hierarchies and use multiple catch statements to catch from more specific to more general. Exception tags are needed to give an exception an identity, somewhat similar to exception class name in Java. `Throw` without a second argument will throw an untagged exception, which can be caught by `Catch` without a second argument. If you seriously want to use exceptions in Mathematica, I would advice against such  usage, since you can easily catch something you did not plan to catch - just as you wouldn't normally use Exception in Java, but would rather subclass it. There are no checked exceptions in Mathematica, so all Mathematica exceptions can be considered run-time exceptions. Since the second argument of `Catch` is a pattern, you can construct `Catch` commands that would be able to catch exceptions with different tags, somewhat emulating the exception inheritance hierarchies of Java. The syntax is also different - there is no `try` - you just wrap `Catch` around a piece of code from where you may expect an exception. Note that Catch with no second argument won't catch a tagged exception, while `Catch` with the second argument won't catch an untagged exception. If you want both, you may need to nest like Catch[Catch[code,pattern]]. There is no `finally` clause provided as a built-in, but one may emulate it with a user-defined code, since in Mathematica one can program the control flow constructs as well, using non-strandard evaluation (functions with Hold-attributes etc). You can look for use cases of `Catch` and `Throw` in the documentation, here on SO posts,and on MathGroup, and you will find plenty o good examples.

HTH

Comment: I strongly agree with using the two-argument form, with an identifiable tag (e.g. not "Failed") to avoid collisions with other code.  Tags do not have to be simple objects; you can use something like Catch[Throw[1 + 1, MyApp`exception["foo"]], _MyApp`exception].

Comment: @Brett  A good point! In cases when the same function  is both throwing and catching an exception, I find the following trick useful - wrap a `Module` around the function like so: `Module[{exc},f[x_,y_]:= Catch[If[x>0||y<0,Throw[something, exc],x+y],exc]]`. In this way, exception tag is guaranteed to be unique, and we don't have to think about it, plus we don't introduce a symbol we should care about (we do create a symbol of course). One such example where this was really useful: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bc41b4a5f51fbcb8

Answer (score 4):

A simple prototype is

```
Catch[
  Check[img = Import["myFile"], Throw[$Failed], Import::nffil];
  Print["Processing image"]
]
```

Where you can make the `Catch` and `Throw` more targeted by using `tag`s if need be.